# What theoretical guarantees are lost in modeling reward as a function of next state?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

There are a couple of threads ([1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97001/what-does-the-reward-function-depend-on-in-a-markov-decision-processes-mdps-i/), [2](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/25717/how-is-that-possible-that-a-reward-function-depends-both-on-the-next-state-and-a)) which address the dependency of reward on the next state in addition to the current state and action. Clearly, modeling the transition probability as a joint distribution over next states and rewards $p(s', r \mid s, a)$ as done in Sutton and Barto's [Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction](http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book.html) is the most general formulation. However, it seems most modern papers (or at least, theoretical papers) formulate reward as a deterministic function $R(s,a)$ of the current state-action pair.

My question is this: **what theoretical guarantees are lost when we generalize reward to be a function of next state in addition to the current state-action pair?** Or perhaps more generally, **why do papers frequently choose to model reward as a deterministic function of state-action pairs**?